# How to use innerHTML by Id or class in php echo and get value from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I'm using javascript to replace the validation code value after pressing the button, the code looks like this:

```js
document.getElementById('showCode').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const icon = this.querySelector('i');
  if (icon.classList.contains('fa-eye')) {
    icon.classList.remove('fa-eye');
    icon.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
    document.getElementById('validCode').innerHTML = 'validationcodehere';
  } else {
    icon.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
    icon.classList.add('fa-eye');
    document.getElementById('validCode').innerHTML = '●●●●●●●●●●●●●●';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <span id='validCode'>●●●●●●●●●●●●●●</span>
        <button id='showCode' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm ms-4'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code above is running fine but not running when put inside php echo. The php7 code I'm using looks like this:

```
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['orderid']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['validation']."</td>";
    echo "<td><span id='validCode'>●●●●●●●●●●●●●●</span><button id='showCode' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm ms-4'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button></td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['order_date']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

My question is how to make it to run in a php echo session and how to get the value of `"document.getElementById('validCode').innerHTML = 'validationcodehere';"` `validationcodehere` the value from the database ".$row['validation']." Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the IDs and replaced with classes.

I also got rid of the dots in the span and put the verification code in a data attribute.

Using classList.toggle I toggle the icon classes on/off.

and I use the repeat function to show a dot for each character in the code.

```js
let showCodeBTN = document.querySelector(".btn-showCode");
showCodeBTN.addEventListener("click", showCode);
  const codeEl = document.querySelector("[data-code]");
  codeEl.innerHTML = "●".repeat(codeEl.getAttribute("data-code").length);


function showCode() {

  const code = codeEl.getAttribute("data-code");

  const icon = this.querySelector('i');
  const showingCode = (icon.classList.contains('fa-eye-slash'));
  icon.classList.toggle("fa-eye");
  icon.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash");
  codeEl.innerHTML = (showingCode) ? "●".repeat(code.length) : code;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-4">
    <span data-code="12345678"></span>
    <button class='btn-showCode btn btn-secondary btn-sm ms-4'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP ECHO:

```
echo "<td><span data-code='{$row['validation']}'></span><button  class='btn-showCode btn btn-secondary btn-sm ms-4'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button></td>";
```

Comment: Hi Imvain2, Thanks for your answer this is brilliant. However when I try it in php echo it doesn't work

Comment: @MaruliDavin I added updated code for your echo

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work in php. Even the toggle function to change the icon doesn't work when I enter php echo. But the code you wrote works fine outside of php, my PHP Version 7.4.13